# Storing user activity in database in JSP/Java

Tags: jsp, authentication, admin, logout

I'm currently working on a project in JSP. How do I store the user login & logout time and the current no. of users online in database? Also I want to check this as an admin and not as a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I store the user login & logout time and the current no. of users online in database?

Here’s a simple [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) example to keep track the total number of active sessions in a web application. If you want to keep monitor your session’s create and remove behavior, then consider this listener.

Sample code:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;
 
public class SessionCounterListener implements HttpSessionListener {
 
  private static int totalActiveSessions;
 
  public static int getTotalActiveSession(){
    return totalActiveSessions;
  }
 
  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    totalActiveSessions++;
    System.out.println("sessionCreated - add one session into counter");
    // database call to log the log in event of the user with current time
  }
 
  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    totalActiveSessions--;
    System.out.println("sessionDestroyed - deduct one session from counter");
    // database call to log the log out event of the user with current time
  } 
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.x.y.z.SessionCounterListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

---

### How it work?

- If a new session is created , e.g `request.getSession();` , the listener’s `sessionCreated()` will be executed.
- If a session is destroyed, e.g session’s timeout or `session.invalidate()`, the listener’s `sessionDestroyed()` will be executed.

Sample code:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(); //sessionCreated() is executed
...
session.invalidate();  //sessionDestroyed() is executed
```

For more info visit [mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/) from where this example is referred.

Comment: So in order for me to see this I create a separate table in the database or view it in the same database with the login info like username and password?

Comment: now you have the the full control where you can capture the  user login and logout events. Just log it in the database along with username or any unique id along with current time.

Comment: Oh well thanks I would completely understand it only after I implement it. So should I write the above code in a bean and call the bea at the time of login?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. write a bean, why? It's listener not a plain POJO class. This class is called automatically by the container. You don't need to call it manually. You have to tell the container that this is my listener and call it when such activities is happened in my application and that is done by defining it in `web.xml` as illustrated in my post.

Comment: OK do it as per your pace and application design. but can you explain me what does it mean *call the bean at the time of login?*

Answer (score 0):

You must create a table, `like log_events(id, event_type, when)` and store login and logout events there whenever they occur.

Comment: How do I store it as an admin to keep track of the users?

Comment: Just make sure you show the records from this table to the admin and none other. As about inserting records, whenever you have a successful login or logout, store the corresponding event in the table.